# Is Ubuntu compatible with MacBooks?

Tags: macbook, apple

Is it possible to install and run Ubuntu on a MacBook?

Comment: To find out boot from a live CD.

Comment: Some of my friends use Ubuntu on MacBooks. No problems AFAICT.

Answer (score 6):

Yes! I am in fact typing this from a MBP 7.1 (where everything except for bluetooth works) :-)

There are comprehensive instructions [on the help wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MacBook).

Answer (score 2):

Yes! And it's getting better! Yesterday I downloaded an optimized official version for the Mac of Natty Alpha1. The page doesn't exists now, but I think Canonical is going to do the same for the Alpha2! :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, even now the Precise Pangolin adds more hardware compatibility. 
the link:

http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/daily-live/current/

worth a spin, mate^^.